# What assets/earnings are included as "income" when determining capital-gains tax rates?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, income, capital-gain

According to [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/capital_gains_tax.asp), people pay varying long-term capital gains tax based on an income-based rate schedule.

[image]

It appears that a person with single tax-filing status who earns less than $39,375 (in 2019) and that sells assets held for more than one year would essentially not pay any capital gains tax.

**My question: is this $39k limit based on just income from a job or does it also include the capital gains as part of this income?**

To help me be sure I understand, could you indicate the tax rate of each of the following single-filing status scenarios?

1. $36k income on W2  +  $4k from selling long-term assets.
2. $10k income on W2  +  $30k from selling long-term assets.
3. $0 income on W2  +  $40k from selling long-term assets.

It seems to me that each of these scenarios would be taxed at the 15% rate, but I'm trying to make sure I understand this correctly.

Comment: Short answer - the brackets include capital gains, but are still marginally-taxed (meaning that not _all_ or your capital gains would be taxed at that level).